# PrestaShop 1.6.1.1 custom module not showing in Front Office

Tags: php, module, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I created mymodule following newest PrestaShop 1.6 documentation. Module is installed and uninstalled right, also css file is added right in header section. But there is no content is displayed in front office.

This is file /module/mymodule/mymodul.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
{exit;
}

class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodule';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'www12';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

        if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
        {$this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');}
    }

    public function install() {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }
        if (!parent::install() ||
                !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') || !$this->registerHook('header') || !Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend')
        ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function uninstall() {
        if (!parent::uninstall() ||
                !Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULE_NAME')
        ) {
            return false;
        } {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = null;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit' . $this->name)) {
            $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('MYMODULE_NAME'));
            if (!$my_module_name || empty($my_module_name) || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name)) {
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
            } else {
                Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', $my_module_name);
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
            }
        }
        return $output . $this->displayForm();
    }

    public function displayForm()
    {
        // Get default language
        $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

        // Init Fields form array
        $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                    'name' => 'MYMODULE_NAME',
                    'size' => 20,
                    'required' => true
                )
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'button'
            )
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();

        // Module, token and currentIndex
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

        // Language
        $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

        // Title and toolbar
        $helper->title = $this->displayName;
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
        $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
        $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
            'save' =>
            array(
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ),
            'back' => array(
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
            )
        );

        // Load current value
        $helper->fields_value['MYMODULE_NAME'] = Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME');

        return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
    }

    public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
    {
      $this->context->smarty->assign(
          array(
              'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
              'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
          )
      );
      return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
    }

    public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)
    {
      return $this->hookDisplayLeftColumn($params);
    }

    public function hookDisplayHeader()
    {
      $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
    }  
}
```

and this is mymodule.tpl file located this same directory:

```
<!-- Block mymodule -->
<div id="mymodule_block_home" class="block">
  <h4>Welcome!</h4>
  <div class="block_content">
    <p>Hello,
       {if isset($my_module_name) && $my_module_name}
           {$my_module_name}
       {else}
           World
       {/if}
       !       
    </p>   
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{$my_module_link}" title="Click this link">Click me!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Block mymodule -->
```

I found [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070520/prestashop-1-6-custom-module-not-displaying-up-on-front-end) but he forgoten important methodes. I did not :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody has the same issue...The code is ok! The problem is that the tutorial says you will find the message on the home but it's not there because **it doesn't have a left column**.

You will find the message on the inner pages (**any with a left column**)

Comment: I'm kinda having the same problems, can you give an example of a page with *left column*?

Comment: There are many of them ... from the homepage just navigate through the links and you'll find one

Answer (score 0):

replace hookdisplayLeftColumn($params) by hookLeftColumn($params)

Answer (score 0):

In your install () method :

`$this->registerHook('leftColumn')`

should be :

`$this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn')`

The name of the hook actually has **"display"** in it if you are referring to the hook that **already exist** in Prestashop(the one used in the front-office).

*What you're actually doing here is creating a **new hook** named "leftColumn" that will get content from hook method named "hookLeftColumn". I think that's not what you want :)*

Comment: then reset the module to install again